# Read select list input from external source in Shiny app (pickerInput)

Tags: r, shiny

I have a simple Shiny app (see below).

I need to read possible selection for  `pickerInput` widget from an external file (it updates frequently).

How can I do this?

The example below is obviously wrong but I have run out of all ideas.

**Example & what I tried**

```
library("shiny")
library("shinyWidgets")

# Actual data: my_choices <- c("2018Q1","2018Q2","2018Q3", "2018Q4", "2019Q1", "2019Q2")

ui <- fluidPage(

  pickerInput(
    inputId = "id",
    label = "SELECT PERIOD:",
    choices = openxlsx::read.xlsx(xlsxFile = 
              "C:/Users/MyName/OneDrive/data.xlsx")$selection, # my_choices
    selected = NULL,
    multiple = TRUE, 
    options = list(
      `actions-box` = TRUE, size = 15, `selected-text-format` = "count > 3"
    ),
    choicesOpt = list(
      content = stringr::str_trunc(my_choices, width = 75)
    )
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$res <- renderPrint(input$id)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here might be one approach. You could use `reactiveFileReader` to periodically load the data file that is updated frequently (you can specify how often to poll). Then use `updatePickerInput` to update your input when the data changes.

I didn't have access to `my_choices` so I commented that out.

```
library("shiny")
library("shinyWidgets")
library("openxlsx")

# my_choices <- c("2018Q1","2018Q2","2018Q3", "2018Q4", "2019Q1", "2019Q2")

ui <- fluidPage(

  pickerInput(
    inputId = "id",
    label = "SELECT PERIOD:",
    choices = NULL,
    selected = NULL,
    multiple = TRUE, 
    options = list(
      `actions-box` = TRUE, size = 15, `selected-text-format` = "count > 3"
    )#,
    #choicesOpt = list(
    #  content = stringr::str_trunc(my_choices, width = 75)
    #)
  ),
  verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "res")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  fileData <- reactiveFileReader(1000,
                                 session,
                                 filePath = 'C:/Users/MyName/OneDrive/data.xlsx', 
                                 readFunc = read.xlsx)

  output$res <- renderPrint(input$id)

  observe({
    updatePickerInput(session, "id", choices = fileData()$selection)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

**Edit**

If you only need to load the file upon launching the app, you would not need the `reactiveFileReader`:

```
observe({
  updatePickerInput(session, "id", choices = openxlsx::read.xlsx(xlsxFile = 
    "C:/Users/MyName/OneDrive/data.xlsx")$selection)
})
```

Alternatively, you can load the file into a dataframe outside of `ui` and reference the dataframe `selection` column in your `pickerInput`.

Comment: No need to actually ping the file. Just read it in again every time the app is launched =) But thanks!

Comment: Ahhh - thanks for clarifying. I can edit the answer to show both alternatives then.